# Creating a 3 by 3 image table with some margin between the images

Tags: tables, graphics

How can I create a 3*3 image table with some margin between images? Which packages do I need?

I am using overleaf.com as platform.

Is a 3*3 image table a good organization for a conference paper? Or how else can I organize 9 images? Should I use a figure?

UPDATE: Could you please have a look and let me know why all my images are shown as black?

```
\begin{figure*}[ht!]
   \subfloat[fig. 1 \label{fig:PKR}]{%
      \includegraphics[ width=0.31\textwidth]{frame_images/1_144.jpg}}
\hspace{\fill}
   \subfloat[fig. 2 \label{fig:PKT} ]{%
      \includegraphics[ width=0.31\textwidth]{frame_images/2_252.jpg}}
\hspace{\fill}
   \subfloat[fig. 3 \label{fig:tie5}]{%
      \includegraphics[ width=0.31\textwidth]{frame_images/3_10541.jpg}}\\



       \subfloat[fig. 4 \label{fig:PKR}]{%
      \includegraphics[ width=0.31\textwidth]{frame_images/4_90131.jpg}}
\hspace{\fill}
   \subfloat[fig. 5 \label{fig:PKT} ]{%
      \includegraphics[ width=0.31\textwidth]{frame_images/5_141.jpg}}
\hspace{\fill}
   \subfloat[fig. 6 \label{fig:tie5}]{%
      \includegraphics[ width=0.31\textwidth]{frame_images/6_110297.jpg}}\\


       \subfloat[fig. 7 \label{fig:PKR}]{%
      \includegraphics[ width=0.31\textwidth]{frame_images/7_10092.jpg}}
\hspace{\fill}
   \subfloat[fig. 8 \label{fig:PKT} ]{%
      \includegraphics[ width=0.31\textwidth]{frame_images/8_10136.jpg}}
\hspace{\fill}
   \subfloat[fig. 9 \label{fig:tie5}]{%
      \includegraphics[ width=0.31\textwidth]{frame_images/9_10287.jpg}}\\
\caption{Examples}
    \label{workflow}
\end{figure*}
```

[image]

Here's what I see:

[image]

Comment: see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/489289/how-to-display-three-figures-in-the-same-line/489293#489293, this row of images you only need to repeat three time ...

Comment: Thank you but how I can avoid having (a), (b), (c), under images?

Comment: See the `floatrow` package. Do you want captions?

Comment: Dear Mona Jalal, this is not `latex` question. how to present your results in article is up-to you. if you not need to captions/sub-captions for each image, than just put them in table (with three rows and columns) with common caption only.

Comment: @Zarko could you please have a look at the updated solution? I used your solution but everything shows as black.

Comment: because you use `\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}`. just remove option `demo`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's fixed now :)

Comment: You might also look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/219756/figure-array-with-top-and-side-captions?r=SearchResults&s=2|33.6380

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see, if the following is what you after:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htb]
  \setkeys{Gin}{width=\linewidth}
  \setlength\tabcolsep{2pt}
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{XXX}
    \includegraphics{example-image-a} &
    \includegraphics{example-image-b} &
    \includegraphics{example-image-c}   \\
    \includegraphics{example-image-a} &
    \includegraphics{example-image-b} &
    \includegraphics{example-image-c}   \\
    \includegraphics{example-image-a} &
    \includegraphics{example-image-b} &
    \includegraphics{example-image-c}
  \end{tabularx}
\caption{Set graphics options by keys "Gin"}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note: from your question and comments is not clear, what is your problem. hopefully this answer will help you clarify your question.